# Opening another workbook on a save event (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

So, I have the code below in my "Thisworkbook" Module.  I need it to run whenever the user saves the workbook.  The code opens another workbook and transfers data into the new workbook.

```
    Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
'Exit Sub
On Error Resume Next
Dim Mas_loc As String

Mas_loc = "C:\Users\J03800\Documents\All Folders\Berry\MasterBerry.xlsx"




Dim n As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim PartNumber As String
Dim CageCode As String
Dim PartCage As String
Dim MI As Integer
Dim ChildWB As Workbook
Dim MasterWB As Workbook
Dim IsMatch As Boolean
Dim ChiMain As Worksheet
Dim MasMain As Worksheet



Set ChildWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set MasterWB = Workbooks.Open(Mas_loc)

Set ChiMain = ChildWB.Sheets("Main")
Set MasMain = MasterWB.Sheets("Main")
n = Application.CountA(ChiMain.Range("B:B")) + 1
m = Application.CountA(MasMain.Range("B:B")) + 1

ChildWB.Activate

For x = 3 To n
    PartNumber = ChiMain.Cells(x, "B").Value
    CageCode = ChiMain.Cells(x, "A").Value
    CSMC = ChiMain.Cells(x, "J").Value
    CMC = ChiMain.Cells(x, "L").Value
    MassObj = ChiMain.Cells(x, "E").Value
    ComObj = ChiMain.Cells(x, "H").Value

    If Len(PartNumber) > 0 Then
        If Len(CageCode) > 1 Then
            PartNumber = "-" & Replace(Replace(PartNumber, CageCode & "-", ""), "-" & CageCode, "")
            PartCage = "Cage-" & CageCode & "-" & PartNumber
        Else
            PartCage = "NoCage-" & PartNumber
        End If
    Else
        PartCage = ""
    End If

    On Error GoTo NewPart
    MatchAddress = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(PartCage, MasMain.Range("K1:K" & m + 20), 0)

    contin:
    On Error Resume Next
    If Len(CSMC) > 0 And Len(Replace(CSMC, "?", "")) = Len(CSMC) And Len(MasMain.Cells(MatchAddress, "E").Value) = 0 Then
        MasMain.Cells(MatchAddress, "E").Value = CSMC
    End If

    If Len(CMC) > 0 And Len(Replace(CMC, "?", "")) = Len(CMC) And Len(MasMain.Cells(MatchAddress, "H").Value) = 0 Then
        MasMain.Cells(MatchAddress, "H").Value = CMC
    End If

    If Len(MassObj) > 0 And Len(Replace(MassObj, "?", "")) = Len(MassObj) And Len(MasMain.Cells(MatchAddress, "C").Value) = 0 Then
        MasMain.Cells(MatchAddress, "C").Value = MassObj
    End If

    If Len(MassObj) > 0 And Len(Replace(MasMain.Cells(MatchAddress, "C").Value, ComObj, "")) = MasMain.Cells(MatchAddress, "C").Value Then
        MasMain.Cells(MatchAddress, "G").Value = MasMain.Cells(MatchAddress, "G").Value & Chr(10) & ComObj
    End If


Next

MasterWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
Exit Sub
    NewPart:
        On Error Resume Next
        m = m + 1
        MatchAddress = m
        MasMain.Cells(MatchAddress, "A").Value = ChiMain.Cells(MatchAddress, "A").Value
        MasMain.Cells(MatchAddress, "B").Value = ChiMain.Cells(MatchAddress, "B").Value
        MasMain.Cells(MatchAddress, "K").Value = PartCage
        GoTo contin

    End Sub
```

The problem seems to be that is is not opening MasterWB.  As, when it bugs out, MasterWB is both not open and according to the code equal to nothing.  What should I change?

Answer (score 0):

Your code block looks fine - assuming the path specified in `Mas_loc` is accurate.

- What errors are you getting when it "bugs out"?
- Have you stepped through the code to see what is happening?

I would comment out the `On Error Resume Next` statement to stop masking any runtime errors.

Comment: It says with block not set, and when I hover over the "MasterWB" it says it is not equal to anything.  The on error resume next, are part of me trying to figure out where the bug was, and circumventing what I thought was a different bug.  I have also run the code several times without and it still will not open masterWB.  Also I am fairly sure the path is correct.  I created a shortcut and copied after I noticed the issue the first time to double check.

Answer (score 0):

I made the sub not private, then it worked